# Is the Microtek 5950 scanner supported on Linux?

Tags: drivers, scanner, linux-device-driver

Is the Microtek 5950 scanner supported on Linux? That is,

- Is there a vendor-released/supported driver for it?
- Is there a FOSS driver for it? Or a driver which it works with?
- Is there any specific functionality of the hardware (e.g. ADF, buttons) which is not supported by the Linux drivers?

Comment: If you actually own a Microtek 5950, first steps to improve the situation are: (1) Connect it via USB, use `lsusb -v`, write down product and vendor id, as well as the device class etc. More difficult: (2) If it's not a standard USB class, install Windows in a VM, get the Windows driver for it, monitor USB traffic and reverse engineer the protocol. Or, get on the SANE mailing lists, ask around if there's anyone willing to help if you provide the USB traces.

Comment: @dirkt: I don't; someone is offering a used one online, and I need to know whether I would be able to use it, if I bought it. +1 though.

Comment: Chances of someone actually owning a Microtek 5950, so he/she can answer your question, and reading this question here in a timely manner are pretty low. There is no good generic way to find out if a concrete device of any kind is supported under Linux (unless you find it in a list), because vendors always invent new stuff, don't document it, and only supply Windows drivers... So it may work because it uses an interface similar to some supported device. Or it may not work.

Comment: @dirkt: Someone who owns any Microtek scanner may know of a different source of drivers for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked on the [SANE project](http://sane-project.org/) website, and there are [no drivers there for the 5950](http://sane-project.org/unsupported/microtek-scanmaker-5950.html). I couldn't find a driver on the [Microtek support website](http://www.microtek.com/service.php) either.

I'm out of ideas, so probably the answer is "not supported". But maybe somebody else can find something I've missed.